# Shield Implementation

Tags: shield-encryption

It would be a great help if you can share your thoughts on the following points:

1. If this is possible to persist data for more than 30 days using Shield ? If not, any alternate approach will be appreciated.
2. Can we track unauthorized data access using shield and generate report or execute analytics ?

Comment: what do you mean by persist data for more than 30 days?. Shield will encrypt the data in rest(in database)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer

> If this is possible to persist data for more than 30 days using Shield ? If not, any alternate approach will be appreciated.

Salesforce shield retains 10 years field history data by default and 60 fields per object can be tracked.

Refer [Field Audit Trail](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=field_audit_trail.htm&type=5)

> Can we track unauthorized data access using shield and generate report or execute analytics ?

Yes, you can track that through Event Monitoring. Refer [Get Started with Event Monitoring](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/event_monitoring/units/event_monitoring_intro)